# Display the context only on the home page; if navigate to other component then the message must be gone

Tags: angular

Say I have a bunch components. Home, One, Two and Three. I use nav and routing to every page.
I want to display a message "Hello" only on Home page. Then in other pages the message must be gone.

[Stackblize](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-docs-routing-navigation-step-5-z6cgdg)

The main structure of app.component.html is

```
<h1>Angular Router</h1>
     <nav>
          <a routerLink="/crisis-center" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
          <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
          <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: ['compose'] } }]">Contact</a>
    </nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<!--router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet-->
<div style='font-size: 50px'>{{title}}</div>
```

You see every page displays "Hello". I don't want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **"Hello"** text is coming on every page because you put it after **router-outlet** tag.

So all the components are being loaded in `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` & then **"Hello"** text is shown after each component.

If you want this text should only on the Home component put this in the respective component template file.

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>Angular Router</h1>
     <nav>
          <a routerLink="/crisis-center" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
          <a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Heroes</a>
          <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { popup: ['compose'] } }]">Contact</a>
    </nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**crisis-center-home.component.html**

```
<p>Welcome to the Crisis Center</p>
<div style='font-size: 50px'>{{title}}</div>
```

**crisis-center.component.ts**

```
export class CrisisCenterComponent {
  title = 'Hello';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can watch for the router event changes and assign a variable when router matches home

```typescript
  title$ = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(({ url }: NavigationEnd) => /^\/crisis-center/.test(url)),
  );
```

You can now use this variable in your template to show the contents you need

```html
<div *ngIf="title$ | async" style='font-size: 50px'>{{title}}</div>
```

[See this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-docs-routing-navigation-step-5-wjfhq7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Just move `<div style='font-size: 50px'>{{title}}</div>` to the `crisis-center.component.ts`'s template:

#### crisis-center.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  template:  `
    <h2>CRISIS CENTER</h2>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <div style='font-size: 50px'>{{title}}</div>
  `
})
export class CrisisCenterComponent {
  title = 'Hello';
}
```